# How to print 2 elements preceding a certain element from their index in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to print the 2 elements that precede any `decl_stmt` element in the children list.
But I keep getting an `indexError: child index out of range`. Any ideas?

```
for count, child in enumerate(children):
     if child.tag == 'decl_stmt':
        print(child[count-2].tag, count)
```

Comment: please post example of how "children" looks like

Comment: You probably mean`print(children[count-2].tag, count)`. This can, however, still behave unexpectedly if `count` is `0` or `1`.

Comment: self.tree = ET.parse(file)
 self.root = self.tree.getroot()
children = self.root.getchildren()

Comment: @schwobaseggl it worked! Yes i see your point about the list's behavior.. Will try to make it more stable. Thank you!

Comment: don't you mean `children[count - 2]` then? `child` is the **current** element. Is this lxml or the standard library [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module?